# Setting C properties from Lua

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have a few values in C that I would like to update from Lua and I've written my own binding functions, but I want to know if something is possible.

I want to be able to do this

```
myNamespace.myValue = 10
```

and have it do the same thing as this

```
myNamespace.setMyValue(10)
```

Possible? Just curious mostly. It's just cleaner to assign/read a value directly instead of calling a get/set function. Can Lua do any auto-translation like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is certainly possible. You can overload the `__newindex` metamethod to translate myValue to `setMyValue` and then call that on the table. An example:

```
local meta = {
    __newindex = function(t, key, value)
        local setterName = "set" .. key:sub(0, 1):upper() .. key:sub(2)
        local setter = t[setterName]
        if setter == nil then
            error("Setter " .. setterName .. " does not exist on table")
        end

        return setter(t, value)
    end
}

local table = {
    setMyValue = function(self, v)
        print("Set value to " .. tostring(v))
    end
}
setmetatable(table, meta)

table.myValue = "Hello"
```

This will print "Set value to Hello".

You might want to overload __index to do the same but with `getMyValue` as well.

Comment: This is per the OP request. Why he would like to write setters for each variable instead of using the `__newindex` method directly I don't know.

Comment: Note that for this to work, `setMyValue` should not write to `myNamespace.myValue`, but to a private table. The `__index` metamethod should read from that table.

Comment: Awesome! I thought this was a total long shot. Lua gets cooler every day, thank you.